# Android - notifyDataSetChanged when I've finished to edit an editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I'm trying to notifydatasetchanged when I've finished to edit an edit text in a recyclerview (why ? because some others objects in recyclerview are accessible only if for exemple the edit text is equals to "test").

So I have an adapter with many view Holders, here is the one for edit text:

```
public EditTextViewHolder(View itemView, final Activity activity, final Context context, final String param) {
    super(itemView);

    this.activity   = activity;
    this.context    = context;
    this.param      = param;


    name        = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tEditTextName);
    desc        = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tEditTextDescription);
    details     = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tEditTextMoreDetails);
    editText    = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.eEditTextValue);
    image       = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iEditTextImage);
    lMain       = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutTaskEditText);
    lOptional   = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutEditTextOptional);
    lRequired   = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.isRequiredTask);

}

 public void setLayout(final Content content) {
    name.setText(content.getTitle());

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            content.getAnswers().get(0).setValue(s.toString().trim());
        }
    });

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus)
                TaskActivity.sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

But I'm getting the error "Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling" even if I try to notify in handler or on ui thread it's not working.

It works with all my others view holders. Do you know what am I doing wrong with edit text ?

Answer (score 0):

> This exception probably occur when you are calling
>   notifyItemInserted(position);, notifyItemChanged(position), or
>   notifyItemRemoved(position); from a background thread (or from a
>   callback, which runs on a background thread).

To solve this, use `Handler` in UI Thread:

```
android.os.Handler mHandler = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getHandler();
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
            //change adapter contents
            mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried this solution once again to be sure, the app doesn't crash but when the edittext lose focus the text simply disappear. I've check the content of my object when I'm writing in the edit text and it's well copied. Or if I have 2 times the same object in recyclerview (edit text) if i edit one and lose focus the text switch to the other edit text ..

Answer (score -1):

try to call notifyDataSetChanged on adapter instead of activity and also call it inside on UIThread.

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {

                                        }
                                    });
```

and make sure inside your adapter has this method with right number of data

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried this solution once again to be sure but it's definitely not working i still have "Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling".  I have many view holders in different files that's why i get my adapter by the activity where the adapter is public static.

Comment: Can you post more of your code. Also where do you call method setLayout?

Comment: setLayout (the name may not be appropriate) is called from onbind function of adapter. I also uset getItemType